# How to access internal memory of HTC Wildfire Buzz with out starting phone

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-wildfire

I have HTC Wildfire Buzz it is very sad to say that i deleted some system files in Internal memory and my htc wildfire can not start  it will restart continue,  but before deleting i have copied all system file in external memory(Memory Card) so please help me how to paste all files in internal memory system folder without starting phone

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you could do that manually. Why not just install the OS again?

Comment: How to install the OS again please help...

Comment: I'd suggest you take your phone to your local HTC dealer, worst case take the phone to some one good with Android phones and ask that person to do it for you. By the sound of it you'll mix up everything and might brick the phone.

Comment: hey good news i stall cyanogenmod successfully,but i cant see googleplay and google apps how its back?